# Ubuntu 22.04. Kubuntu 23 not working webapp on Telegram

Tags: telegram

Ubuntu 22.04. Kubuntu 23 not working webapp on Telegram.
When open on Telegram bot `@asmico_attach_bot` click **Simple webview**, i receive empty window.

[image: empty window]
[image: errors on console]

Comment: Please clarify your release details; Ubuntu's main products are *year.month* in format (eg. 22.04 you mention) with specialist *snap* only products using the *year* format (eg. Ubuntu Core 22 being a *flavor* of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server), but Kubuntu is a desktop thus uses *deb* packages thus cannot run on the *year* products (which only get released on the *even* years anyway; thus no 23 exists).  Do you mean 23.04? or something else?

Answer (score -1):

Kubuntu 23.04, Ubuntu 22.04, Telegram 4.8.3

[image: Kubuntu]
[image: Ubuntu]

Comment: Is this an answer to your question?   You've posted it as an answer but I don't see that it answers your question sorry.  Don't forget this is a Q&A site and not a forum. Well done for solving your issue if you solved it as stated.  *You can edit your own questions & correct details there, but you've now marked this question as self-answered*